# C, kill all processes

Tags: c

I have a project for school and I need some help.
I'm working in C and I have a server and a client. In server I make a new process for each client with fork. My question is: if I close the server with CTRL+C, how do I kill all the remaining processes ? Thanks

Comment: Do you want a shell-script that does it, or do it in the server program?

Comment: @user1929959 Zombie processes are already dead.

Comment: i want it in the server program, OS: linux, POSIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it for you in the shell:

```
killall -15 <process name>
```

In C, you can try:

```
kill(0, SIGKILL)
```

in the `SIGINT` signal handler for your main server process to kill all the processes in its process group, which should include its children.

Answer (score 2):

You can store their pids after they are created and then, when quitting, signal `sigterm` or `sigkill` to them.

You can do it through shell - `killall` is what you are searching for under linux.

You could use threads instead of processes (could you? what do the project details say?) and communicate through variables.

Comment: yes, I could use threads but I already finished the project.. a lot of work if i want to modify it for using threads. I have only this thing to do to finish it, and I know that my teacher will try it: CTRL+C on server, clients still running, that's no good.., thanks for your answer, i will try it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that this'd be implementation-defined. You'll need to keep the PIDs for the forks, hook the [signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/signal.html) that CTRL+C sends to your server (SIGINT in POSIX) and kill them using whichever method your OS recommends ([kill](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/kill.html) in POSIX environments).

Answer (score 0):

When you kill a process alone, it will not kill the children.

You have to send the signal to the process group if you want all processes for a given group to receive the signal: `kill -9 -parentpid`. Otherwise, orphans will be linked to `init`,